# factorial from-scratch generates multiple outputs in RStudio

Tags: r

I know there's a built-in function, but I was messing around with making factorials from scratch as an idea from a coding website I was reading through. Code is here:

```
recursion <- function(n) {

  if(n <= 1) {
    print(1)
  } else { 
    print(n * recursion(n-1))
  }
}
```

70% of the time I get this output:

```
> recursion(5)
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 6
[1] 24
[1] 120
```

but 30% of the time I get:

```
> recursion(5)
[1] 120
```

Can anyone help me understand why this could be, and what I can to do get only one output?

not sure if this is allowed, but I'm getting the same problem when trying to implement memoization too.

```
memoization <- function(){
  values <- 1
  Factorial_mem <- function(x){
    if(x < 0){
      stop("Factorials can only be computed when x is equal to, or greater 
        than, zero")
    }
    if (x == 0 | x == 1){
      return(1)
    } 
    if (length(values) < x){
      values <<- `length<-`(values, x)
    }
    if (!is.na(values[x])){
      return(values[x])
    }
    values[x] <<- x * factorial(x-1)
    print(values)

  }
  Factorial_mem
}
```

output some of the time:

```
> Factorial_mem(5)
[1] 120
```

output most of the time:

```
> Factorial_mem(5)
[1] 1 NA NA NA 120
```

If I need to provide additional info for clarification please let me know and I can provide it. I'm not sure if the fact that I'm using RStudio is pertinent or not.

Thank you

Comment: You're calling your function `for_loop`, but you're using `recursion` in your first example. So is it `for_loop` or `recursion`?

Comment: sorry.. it's recursion. fixed.

Comment: Your `print(x)` should be inside `for(i in 1:n)`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue using `replicate(1000, recursion(5))`. You'll need provide more context on the 70-30% split

Comment: hey thanks CPak. The only other information I can provide is that I'm running a for_loop, reduce, recursion, and memoization function all at the same time from one script. I'm wondering if that's why the output is generating oddly?

Comment: Do you really just want it printing directly instead of returning the result?

Comment: Dason, yes. In this situation the exercise calls for it. Also, If I return the outputs, nothing prints :(